# Cayley-Hamilton to find a power of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& -1\\ -1&-1&0\\ 0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, which has characteristic polynomial $P(t)=t^3+1$.
Cayley-Hamilton gives us that $P(A)=A^3+I_3=0$, how can I use this to find $A^{100}$?

Comment: $A^{100} = A\cdot (A^3)^{33}$

Comment: @DanielFischer So $A^{100}=-A$?

Comment: @JimmyP Yes, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$A^{100}=A\cdot(A^3)^{33}=A\cdot(-I_3)^{33}=A\cdot-I_3=A$

Thanks go out to @DanielFischer and @VaibhavJena